# Javascript function behind checkbox in Gridview

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have Javascript Function that works correctly when the checkbox is checked i.e. sets 'Chk' to true but not when the checkbox is unchecked i.e. also sets 'Chk' to true. The Function then passes two parameters to a second page which runs a Stored Proc (setting a value to true or false).
Here is my code:

```
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myfunction(invId, Chk) {
    var chkboxValue = ($("#iSelect").is(":checked") ? false : true);
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "upDateMe.aspx?param1=" + invId +"&param2=" + chkboxValue,
        data: "",
        contentType: "text/html",
        dataType: "text"
    });
}
```

Comment: What happens when the checkbox is unchecked? Doesn't work is not enough information :)

Comment: how do you call your function?

Comment: And the question is...?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the checkbox status value by using this

```
var chkboxValue = ($("#iSelect").prop('checked'));
```

this will fetch whether it is true or false 
Your function should like this

```
function myfunction(invId, Chk) {
    var chkboxValue = ($("#iSelect").prop('checked'));
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "upDateMe.aspx?param1=" + invId +"&param2=" + chkboxValue,
        data: "",
        contentType: "text/html",
        dataType: "text"
    });
}
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/QRNyJ/1/) is the fiddle that you want: http://jsfiddle.net/QRNyJ/1/

Comment: Thanks but I get - Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'prop'

Comment: You should use jquery 1.6 or greater